# will_paginate: how to build a "next page" link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I know this must be REALLY simple but after looking around I cannot find the answer.

I'm using the will_paginate plugin and I like to have a simple "next page" link instead of the whole will_paginate link collection.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This will give you just a simple next button to work with.

```
protected

# Tells WP how to render the "Next Page" link
  def next_page
    # The only difference from the default here is we renamed the link to "More"
    # and added a custom class, twitter_pagination
    previous_or_next_page(@collection.next_page, "Next", 'twitter_pagination') if @collection.next_page
  end

  # Remove all links except our :next_page
  def pagination
    [ :next_page ]
  end
```

Let us know how you get on. Here is a great [Blog Posts](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2010/8/22/revisited-roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate-and-rails-3) you should read as well. Let us know how you get on. All the best.

Comment: In lib/pagination_list_link_renderer.rb - Have a look at the link I added and have a look at this post as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122314/rails-autoloading-lib-not-working/6122356#6122356

Comment: I'm sorry to disturb you again, I read the 2 articles (also the one referring to Rails 2.3.6 cause I'm not using Rails 3).  Also looked at the post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122314/rails-autoloading-lib-not-working/6122356#6122356), added the above code to my lib directory, but if I call <%= will_paginate(@events, :renderer => PaginationListLinkRenderer) %> I still get the usual will_paginate link collection :(

Comment: Here we go - This should do the trick http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/8/3/roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate

Answer (score 2):

It actually is a little more involved than you'd think to do it how some might call the "Rails Way". http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/8/3/roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate

But you can also just make a helper and use the methods `current_page` and `total_pages`. So something like:

```
<% if @post.current_page < @post.total_pages %>
   <%= link_to "Next", "#{posts_path(@post)}?page=#{@post.current_page+1}" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using will_paginate v3 on Rails v4:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :page_links=>false %>
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove the previous link as well? I would like to only display a "next" button.

Comment: @flyingL123 with css rule: `.pagination .prev { display: none }`

Comment: Actually when I pass in `page_links: false`, the `.next` and `.prev` classes no longer appear on the list items. I was forced to set `display:none` then `display:block` for the `:last-child`. Is this intentional?

Comment: Apologies I forgot I'm using the bootstrap will_paginate gem which I think explains the existence of prev and next classes? https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/will_paginate-bootstrap

Comment: Weird, I am using that too, but the classes are removed when I use `page_links: false`. Strange. I'm using `bootstrap-will_paginate 0.0.10` and `will_paginate 3.0.7`.