# Rails: Autoloading lib not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, loader

For some reason my autoloader isn't working, i followed some tutorials, here is what my config\application.rb file looks like

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

module Quotes
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
        config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

I am getting this error:
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::PaginationListLinkRenderer

Here is my lib\paginationlistlinkrenderer.rb code

```
class PaginationListLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ViewHelpers::LinkRenderer

    protected
    ...
    ...

end
```

Here is my index.html.erb

```
<div id="img_content">
    <%= render @posts%>
</div>

<%= will_paginate(@posts, :renderer => PaginationListLinkRenderer) %>
<%= link_to "New Quote", new_post_path %>
```

I just need to get this file to pre-load so my controller will recognize it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your config/initializers folder make a file called pagination.rb and include the following. Restart and it should work.

```
module WillPaginate::ViewHelpers
    # default options that can be overridden on the global level
    @@pagination_options = {
      :class        => 'pagination',
      :previous_label   => '&laquo; Previous',
      :next_label   => 'Next &raquo;',
      :inner_window => 2, # links around the current page
      :outer_window => -1, # links around beginning and end
      :limit        => 5,
      :separator    => ' ', # single space is friendly to spiders and non-graphic browsers
      :param_name   => :page,
      :params       => nil,
      :gap          => "...",
      :renderer     => '::PaginationListLinkRenderer',
      :page_links   => true,
      :container    => true
    }
    mattr_reader :pagination_options
end
```

Change you Lib pagination File to...

```
pagination_list_link_renderer.rb
```

Make sure you have the latest version of Will_Pagination. Version 3 Pre

Comment: nice that worked, what the heck was going on ?? =/ so confused lol

Comment: Have a read through these - # LINKS
Faster Cucumbering With Pagination - http://rubyflare.com/2010/11/25/faster-cucumbering-with-pagination/
Roll your own pagination links with will_paginate - http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/8/3/roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate
Roll your own pagination links with will_paginate Revisited - http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2010/8/22/revisited-roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate-and-rails-3
Building custom pagination links with will_paginate - http://fr.ivolo.us/posts/building-custom-pagination-links-with-will_paginate

Comment: thank you, i was following thewebfellas tutorial, hopefully the other links will also provide more insight, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

**lib\paginationlistlinkrenderer.rb** code

```
class PaginationListLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ViewHelpers::LinkRenderer

    protected
    ...
    ...

end
```

To

```
class PaginationListLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer

    protected
    ...
    ...

end
```