# Will paginate issue in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I have an application which paginates two Models at and based on the number of results can have a collection of the `two models or one` which is in turned paginated so that the total count of the collection is always 12 ( the per page count).

Now since I pass the `total_entries` with my final pagination, I have the total number of pages correct, however the `current_page` always remains `1` since the collection size is always `12`.

How can I modify the view helper to make WP to change the page number according to the `params[:page]` that I send.

The links that appear for page 2 and 3 etc are clickable and lead to correct paginated results but always remains in page 1 with `next_page` link not working.

**This is my pagination in the view**

```
<%= will_paginate @collection, :renderer => "RemoteLinkRenderer", :params => {:controller => 'doc_managers',:action => @action} %>
```

**This my individual and final paginate in the controller**

```
f = Folder.action_folder_collection(@action, current_user).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 12)
if (f.count < 12)
  #d = Document.action_document_collection(@action, current_user)
  d = Document.action_document_collection(@action, current_user).paginate(:page => d_page(params[:page], fc, dc), :per_page => per_page-f.count)
end

@collection = collection.flatten.paginate(:page => page(params[:page], collection.flatten.size),:per_page => 12, :total_entries => total)
```

Now since `@collection` is always paginated and its size is `12` always, this stays in page `1`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can define `:per_page` option in your `will_paginate` to show total pages per page.

```
<%= will_paginate @collection, :renderer => "RemoteLinkRenderer", :params => {:controller => 'doc_managers',:action => @action}, :per_page => 12 %>
```

If you want to build the `next page` link then follow [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121448/will-paginate-how-to-build-a-next-page-link?rq=1).

Comment: The per_page thing doesn't work. As I said it already paginates it to 12 per page and also shows correct number of pages but since each collection has only 12 entries at a time the page number selected is always 1.

Comment: Do not use it for collection basis, do it for per page basis. You need to remove pagination from `@collection` and instead use it in `will_paginate` as I mentioned above.

Comment: Removing it from @collection doesn't show any paginate links. It shows 1st page only with 12 entries which is the 12 from my paginated results of Folder Model.